# TypeError: Object of type Client is not JSON serializable when using langchain

Tags: python-3.x, langchain, py-langchain

I just learned langchain and I'm encountering an issue with langchain resulting in a TypeError: Object of type Client is not JSON serializable. This error arises when I try to execute the following simple code:

```
template = """Tell me a {adjective} joke about {subject}."""
prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["adjective", "subject"])
llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=config.openaiExample, verbose=True)

llm_chain.predict(adjective="sad", subject="ducks")
```

The error occurs after the formatted prompt is generated:

```
> Entering new LLMChain chain...
Prompt after formatting:
Tell me a sad joke about ducks.
```

The complete traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ianhui/code/bpe/bpe-python/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    llm_chain.predict(adjective="sad", subject="ducks")
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py", line 293, in predict
    return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_key]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 312, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 306, in __call__
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py", line 103, in _call
    response = self.generate([inputs], run_manager=run_manager)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm.py", line 115, in generate
    return self.llm.generate_prompt(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 516, in generate_prompt
    return self.generate(prompt_strings, stop=stop, callbacks=callbacks, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 666, in generate
    output = self._generate_helper(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 553, in _generate_helper
    raise e
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_core/language_models/llms.py", line 540, in _generate_helper
    self._generate(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py", line 1146, in _generate
    full_response = completion_with_retry(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py", line 122, in completion_with_retry
    return _completion_with_retry(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 289, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 379, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 314, in iter
    return fut.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py", line 382, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/langchain_community/llms/openai.py", line 120, in _completion_with_retry
    return llm.client.create(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 216, in request
    result = self.request_raw(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 509, in request_raw
    abs_url, headers, data = self._prepare_request_raw(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 481, in _prepare_request_raw
    data = json.dumps(params).encode()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 200, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 258, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Client is not JSON serializable
```

It seems the error occurs during the JSON serialization process within the OpenAI API call. I'm not sure why the Client object is not serializable in this context. Has anyone else faced this issue, and what could be the potential solution? Is this problem related to the version?

iam using **Python 3.11.5**,
**langchain             0.0.352
langchain-community   0.0.3
langchain-core        0.1.1
langsmith             0.0.71**

Comment: Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: can u post `config.openaiExample`  used here `llm=config.openaiExample,`